# When I rotate the screen, my activity restart? how can I stop this?

Tags: android, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

I connect to i ip-cam with thread. When I rotate screen, activity restart and new thread restart?? I only want to set ImageView fullscreen when ı rotate... How can I stop activity-restart???

```
public class ViewCam extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Bitmap bmp = null;
private String bmpl = null;
private ImageButton UpButton;
private ImageButton DownButton;
private ImageButton LeftButton;
private ImageButton RightButton;
private ImageButton ZoomInButton;
private ImageButton ZoomOutButton;
private ImageButton butlisten;
ImageView imageView;
TextView imagetext;
long id;
Thread My;
private Runnable viewCams;
private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null;
private ArrayList<ImageView> imageArray;
private Gallery gallery;

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        try {

            bmp = CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam.getCurrentImage();
            bmpl = CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam.getCurrentLenght();
            if (bmp != null) {
                if (CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam.isConnected())
                    m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                imagetext.setText(bmpl);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            sleep();
        }

    };

    public void sleep() {
        this.removeMessages(0);

        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), 50);

    };
};

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (CameraManagerScreen.ROTATION == 0) {
        My = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam.go();
                    // upLoadCam();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            };
        };
        My.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    CameraManagerScreen.ROTATION = 1;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam.cancel();
    CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam.setConnected(false);

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setFullscreen();
    setContentView(R.layout.viewcam);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myView);
    imagetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageText);
    gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    UpButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.UpButton);
    DownButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.DownButton);
    LeftButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.LeftButton);
    RightButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.RightButton);
    ZoomInButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ZoomInButton);
    ZoomOutButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ZoomOutButton);

    UpButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    DownButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    LeftButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    RightButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    ZoomInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    ZoomOutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    // gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    if (CameraManagerScreen.ROTATION == 0) {
        m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ViewCam.this,
                "Please wait...", "Connecting ...", true);
        m_ProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        m_ProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        // Thread gThread=new Thread(){
        // public void run(){gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));}
        // };

        handler.sendMessage(new Message());
    }
}
public void setFullscreen() {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}

private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // if (cameras != null && cameras.size() > 0) {
        // c_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // for (int i = 0; i < cameras.size(); i++)
        // c_adapter.add(cameras.get(i));
        // }
        // m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // c_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

// private void upLoadCam() {
// imageArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
// for (int i = 0; i < CameraManagerScreen.cameras.size(); i++) {
// if(CameraManagerScreen.cameras.get(i)
// .getImageForGallary()!=null)
// imageArray.add(CameraManagerScreen.cameras.get(i)
// .getImageForGallary());
// }

// }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == UpButton) {

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam.goPTZ(CameraType.PTZ_UP);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            };
        };
        t.start();
    }
    if (v == DownButton) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam
                            .goPTZ(CameraType.PTZ_DOWN);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            };
        };
        t.start();
    }
    if (v == LeftButton) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam
                            .goPTZ(CameraType.PTZ_LEFT);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            };
        };
        t.start();
    }
    if (v == RightButton) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam
                            .goPTZ(CameraType.PTZ_RIGHT);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            };
        };
        t.start();
    }
    if (v == ZoomInButton) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam
                            .goPTZ(CameraType.PTZ_ZOOM_IN);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            };
        };
        t.start();
    }
    if (v == ZoomOutButton) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CameraManagerScreen.ActiveCam
                            .goPTZ(CameraType.PTZ_ZOOM_OUT);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            };
        };
        t.start();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Maybe this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android

Comment: It is possible to stop the Activity from being re-created, but you probably shouldn't attempt it.  Instead, you should be writing your code the way Google intended you to write it.  If you do this, it should not matter.